# Forbidden You don't have permission to access {codeigniter} on this server

Tags: codeigniter, apache2

I am trying to run CodeIgniter for the first time. I have a running apache2 server on my machine. I downloaded CodeIgniter and copy extracted folder  it into `/var/www/html` folder. Also, I set `baseUrl` config in CodeIgniter

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/codeIgniter';
```

But I am getting

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /codeIgniter/ on this server.
```

I tried setting .htaccess file but couldn't fix the issue. what is the solution for this issue?

Comment: In the HTML folder do: chown -R www-data:www-data nameOfProject

Comment: it worked. Please put this as the answer

Comment: Glad it worked for you!

Comment: can you mark it as the answer that worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty vague question but here are some trouble shooting things.

In the HTML folder do: chown -R www-data:www-data nameOfProject.

Also did you set up everything in your apache/sites-available and sites-enabled. Also set up your host file

If this doesn't work just google setting up a ci project.

The reason you had to chown it was to allow appache to access it

Comment: I just followed CodeIgniter documentation to install it